# How do I know the taylor series of sine converges at all?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Unlike potential duplicates, this question does not relate to sine or how you arrive at its taylor series, rather, the series itself. The same question could be asked of cosine, and several other taylor series that come to mind.

$\sin{x}=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+ \ ...$

I know sine is often defined in this way, and that we can prove other sine definitions give the same result. What I am interested in is how we can forget about the LHS, or this series being sine at all, and look only at the RHS and determine it converges for all x. Factorials get pretty big fast, but when $x$ is greater than the number inside the factorial, it doesnt look convincing. How can I know for sure that the LHS converges?

Comment: You're right, but what happens at the beginning is irrelevant to convergence. Did you try the ratio test?

Comment: Easy one: if you're interested in maths and convergence, you learn convergence tests. If you're not... what's wrong with gardening?!

Comment: yes, when $|x|>n$ it looks bad. But $x$ is fixed; for all but finitely many $n$ you have $|x|<n$.

Comment: Well, what you say shows that numerically, the Taylor series is useless for computing $\sin x$ for large values of $x$, but the series converges for all real $x$ for reasons others have given.